# Sort number javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to sort the numbers that are drawn here from smallest to largest in the tables so that the table does not delete. How do I do that?

```html
<html>
<head>
<title> Numery losowania </title>
<script>
    var n1= new Array (9);
    for(var i=0; i<n1.length;i++)
    {
        var rand= Math.floor(Math.random()*70);
        n1[i] = rand;
    }
 
    document.writeln("<table border = \"1\"");
   
    for(var i=0; i < n1.length;i++)
    {
        document.writeln("<tr><td>" + n1[i] + "</td></tr>");
    }
    document.writeln("</table>");
</script>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Odśwież" onclick="location.reload()">
</form>
</head>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You have not asked us any actual question yet. (And it doesn’t look much like you did actual proper research before asking either.)

Comment: `so that the table does not delete`?

Comment: the table was deleting after attempting to sort numbers, i dont know why

Comment: @Mivalia I fixed my answer, does it work for you now?

Comment: @Luca yeah it works :)

Comment: Kindly mark the question as answered then, this helps users identify working answers!

Comment: @Luca Okey, thank You !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `n1.sort();` before the loop.

> The default sort order is according to string Unicode code points.

So you need to pass a function to it for sorting:

```
n1.sort((a,b) => a-b);
```

This will make sure that the lower numbers are first

For filling the array, use `Array.from()` this will save you some code

```html
<html>
<head>
<title> Numery losowania </title>
<script>
    var n1= Array.from({length: 9}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 70));
 
    document.writeln("<table border = \"1\"");

    n1.sort((a,b) => a-b); // sort the array
   
    for(var i=0; i < n1.length;i++)
    {
        document.writeln("<tr><td>" + n1[i] + "</td></tr>");
    }
    document.writeln("</table>");
</script>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Odśwież" onclick="location.reload()">
</form>
</head>
```

Comment: It does not. your sort result is 0
18
26
43
45
5
56
64
8

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Numery losowania </title>
<script>
    var n1= new Array (9);
    for(var i=0; i<n1.length;i++)
    {
        var rand= Math.floor(Math.random()*70);
        n1[i] = rand;
    }

    document.writeln("<table border = \"1\"");
   n1.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
    for(var i=0; i < n1.length;i++)
    {
        document.writeln("<tr><td>" + n1[i] + "</td></tr>");
    }
    document.writeln("</table>");
</script>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Odśwież" onclick="location.reload()">
</form>
</head>
</html>
```